# Vuejs unable to access local json file using axios. 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

After trying working around it a lot to fetch JSON data from the local file.
Always receiving the following error: `GET http://localhost:8080/test.json 404 (Not Found)`.
The project has been created using vue-cli.

File has been kept under public folder -
[image]

File content is -

```
{
    "content": "SwiftUI was introduced in iOS 13 in a time many of us have a big app built with UIKit. SwiftUI"
}
```

Template -

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{blogcontent.content}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Script -

```
<script>
 
import axios from "axios";
const ax = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
});

export default {
  name: "BloePage",
  data() {
    return {
      blogcontent: { content: "Loading..." },
    };
  },
  mounted() {

    let url = "test.json";
    ax.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        this.blogcontent = response;
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: So the page loads correctly at `http://localhost:8080/index.html` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX it's loading correctly. just received this error message, because it was unable to find json file locally.

Comment: and if you point your browser to `http://localhost:8080/test.json` this also works?

Comment: @JaromandaX nothing happens. Loading home screen. but if I'm using relative path with import, its working fine. Which I don't want. I need to keep that file name dynamic in future.

Comment: when running the `serve` script, you can usually use one of two addresses, `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://x.x.x.x:8080/` ... where the x.x.x.x is your computers IP address ... have you tried both?

Comment: `nothing happens` - no error? you should get a 404 error

Comment: I haven't tried http://x.x.x.x:8080/ till now.

Comment: Tried http://x.x.x.x:8080/ just now and it failed. net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: so, using your IP address, you get a different error?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes.

Comment: how odd ... so `npm run server` looks OK, no errors?

Comment: shall I hit `npm run server` command in vuejs project terminal in root directory? Normally I use `vue serve`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I'm new to vue. So I'm not much aware about using `npm run server`.

Comment: I don't use `vue serve` I use `yarn run serve` (same as `npm run serve`) to run the server ... I don't install the `@vue/cli-service-global` pesonally

Comment: @JaromandaX `yarn run serve` worked for me that day. I think restarted the project and later it started working...

Answer (score 1):

I have just edited this part of your code:

```
this.blogcontent.content = response.data.content;
```

and it works fine

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{blogcontent.content}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 
import axios from "axios";
const ax = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
});

export default {
  name: "BloePage",
  data() {
    return {
      blogcontent: { content: "Loading..." },
    };
  },
  mounted() {

    let url = "test.json";
    ax.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        this.blogcontent.content = response.data.content;
        console.log(response.data.content);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: @kiran_jasvanee Please mark my answer as correct answer if it solved you problem.